Random Cut Forest on Multiple Timeseries anomaly detection
I am trying to find anomaly on multiple sensor data using random cut forest, how can i use random cut forest for multi times series data.
i have created a model for one time series data and that works well, at the same time i have to detect anomaly for multiple timeseries.



There is a sample for multivariate anomaly detection with RCF here:
https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-anomaly-detection-with-rcf-and-deepar/blob/main/2.RandomCutForest.ipynb
Hope this helps.

Thanks checked this out before, here the anomalies are correlated with each time series, so assigning anomaly score are matching for all the time series, but in my case anomalies are different for different times series, Deep AR is a solution though
